# How to export and download data into valid xlsx format on client side?

Tags: javascript, excel, vue.js, ecmascript-6

From the backend api I am getting a list of students data into a valid excel file which is being downloaded on hitting the endpoint /api/v1.0/students/students-xlsx/ But on the client side when I am calling this endpoint it's showing unreadable format and being downloaded as a corrupt excel file.

I followed some stackoverflow suggestions like atob, encodeURI the response data and add specific type (UTF-8) but it failed. Still I am getting the corrupt file with weird characters.

```
excelFileDownload() {
  this.$http.get(this.exportXLUrl)
    .then((response) => {
      response.blob().then(() => {
        const blob = new Blob([response.body], { type: response.headers.get('content-type') });
        const filename = response.headers.map['content-disposition'][0].split('filename=')[1];
        const link = document.getElementById('download-excel-file');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = filename.split('"').join('');
        link.style.display = 'block';
        link.click();
      });
    });
},
```

I expect the output as same as when I am just using browsable API to call the endpoint- which is giving me the appropriate xls format file with readable characters. But on the client side I am not getting that at all. It's all broken. Any help would be appreciated to improve my code.

Comment: If you put yourdomain.com/api/v1.0/students/students-xlsx/ on the browser, does the browser download the file?

Comment: Yes it does @ItsaMeTuni

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I need to pass the Content-type in headers and responseType with the get request as below:

```
headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.openxmlformatsofficedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet' },
responseType: 'arraybuffer'
```

It works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use `XMLHttpRequest`

(untested)

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', this.exportXLUrl, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.addEventListener('load', () =>
{
    if(xhr.status == 200)
    {
        const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);

        const contentDisposition = xhr.getResponseHeader('content-disposition');
        const filename = /filename=([^;]*)/.exec(contentDisposition)[1];

        const link = document.getElementById('download-excel-file');
        link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        link.download = filename.split('"').join('');
        link.style.display = 'block';
        link.click();

        //Dont forget to revoke it
        window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    }
    else
    {
        //error
    }
});

xhr.addEventListener('error', err =>
{
    //error
});

xhr.send();
```

Comment: I tried this way but it's not working. I am using Vue.JS here

Comment: What happens? Any console errors? What headers are you sending in you server response?

Comment: `GET /api/v1.0/students/students-xlsx/ HTTP/1.1
Host: [Host URL]
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Authorization: Token 6200840e7f0bd84c06c9d990fc5abcd670475f83
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.120 Safari/537.36
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Referer:[url]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;`

Comment: No console errors. It's just the characters being downloaded in unreadable format like this: `PK¢VOdocProps/app.xmlM=1DÿÊq½·AÁBb@ÐR°²{/dC²B~¾9ÁnoFß
g*â©-Tã"¶N]§nh¥cy;çÎÏHI`«Ô¨ ¥æMþFr­xNæê±pe'Ã¥!
ÿrmÞ©Ô5ï&õÖð;i^PKAMb±PK¢VOdocProps/core.xmlÍQKÃ0Ç¿ä½½$e¡ëcO
Å·Ü¶`ä¤Ý··­[èð1wÿüîwpµÊt S1Ã|3ø6deâ¢Èæ^çrL±¹ï×4>Ó¢6ú 9¿¤­&
°5µ5Ê$ÔÔ¥3Þ?S;Ã¬lÑc ¢Àib<`

Comment: Response headers: `HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
connection: close
server: gunicorn/19.9.0
date: Tue, 22 Oct 2019 02:52:13 GMT
content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
content-disposition: attachment; filename="students.xlsx"
vary: Accept, Accept-Language, Cookie, Origin
allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
content-length: 22112
content-language: en
strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
via: 1.1 vegur`